# Finding the column index by its name in R

Tags: r

In a data frame, I would like to get the column's index by name.  For example:

```
x <- data.frame(foo=c('a','b','c'),bar=c(4,5,6),quux=c(4,5,6))
```

I want to know the column index for "bar".

I came up with the following but it seems inelegant.  Is there a more straightforward builtin that I am missing?

```
seq(1,length(names(x)))[names(x) == "bar"]
[1] 2
```

Comment: `match("bar",names(x))` also works, though `match` is much more useful when the first argument is also a vector.

Comment: Do you actually need the column's index? You can also use x[,"bar"] to get the entire column, similar to the usual x\$bar. And in both cases, subscript the rows: x[2:3, "bar"] or x\$bar[2:3]. If you need to feed the index to a routine that requires an index, that's not helpful, of course.

Comment: Bah, it keeps messing up my dollar signs. The bottom line is that there are two ways to use a column's name the dollar sign method and including it as a subscript.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something in R, & not about any related statistical issues.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

probably this is the simplest way:

```
which(names(x)=="bar")
```

Answer (score 12):

just to add another possibility:
You can usually use `grep` and it's decedents (i.e., grepl,  to do these kind of jobs in a more sophisiticated way using regular expressions.

On your example your could get the column index with:

`grep("^bar$", colnames(x))` or `grep("^bar$", names(x))`

The `^` and `$` are meta characters for the beginning and end of a string, respectively.

Check ?grep and especially ?regex for more infos (i.e., you can grab only partial names/matches, or the return value is the string itself or a logical vector,...)

For me, `grep` is more R-ish.

Strongly related is the recent package by Hadley Wickhem: [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html), A package for "modern, consistent string processing" including grep like functions. He recently published [a paper on it in the R Journal.](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Wickham.pdf)

[See also my answer on stackoverflow on an identical issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427234/get-column-index-from-label-in-a-data-frame/4427459#4427459)